# How upload the app for specific city in the Google Play Console?

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console

I want upload app for specific city.

How can I restrict the app for specific city in the Google Play Console?

Answer (score 0):

actually you can't upload for a specific city. You can do it for a Country.

Maybe you can use solutions that "blocks" the app using the geoposition of the device

Answer (score 0):

In Play store, You can restrict for a country. But Not for a specific city or region.
If this requirement is strictly needed, you can get the location permission from the user, then find the city based on coordinates. after that you can restrict the user.

Comment: This doesn't prevent those users to give my app a 1 start rating, that's the problem. Those aren't my target population at all yet I had to face 1 star rating.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Service has country wise publish. You can't publish with city restriction on Google Play Service.
You could restrict user using geo location within your app.